# Как компилятор TypeScript понимает чем является T в типе Equal

Tags: typescript

Реализация типа `Equal` из [type-challenges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges):

```
type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false
```

Моё понимание работы типа `Equal`:

Тип `Equal` принимает два обобщённых типа `X` и `Y`. В условие проверяется сопоставление результатов функций, которые проверяют сопоставление обобщённых типов с обобщённым типом `T`. Если переданные обобщённые типы `X` и `Y` одинаковые, то условный тип будет выглядеть так: `1 extends 1 ? true : false`.А результатом будет `true`.

Но я никак не могу понять, что и как *TypeScript* подставляет в `T`. Как он определяет контекст, если `T` определяется автоматически? И чем будет `T`?

Comment: https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/225
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо за ссылку, но кроме таких же как я, непонимающих как это работает, больше ничего не нашел. Нет описания как это работает.

Comment: _условный тип будет выглядеть так: `1 extends 1`_ - нет, он будет выглядеть не так

Comment: Вот тут есть пояснение: [How does the `Equals` work in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68963796/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за ссылку. 1. Вы можете дать свой ответ для русско-говорящего сообщества? 2. В всех примерах автор явно прокидывает типы, а комментарии к ответу ещё больше навели смуты в моей голове. Мне понятно пока только одно, что `T` будет устанавливаться автоматически исходя из контекста, но какой он именно выбирается не понятно. И функции же не вызываются..

Comment: `T` никак не устанавливается, это просто generic тип.

Comment: @Grundy может я не так выразился, я имел в виду не устанавливается, а подменяется. Например типом `string`.  И что значит просто generic? `Array<T>` - это generic и вместо `T` будет тот тип, который передадим. А `<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2)` - сокращённая  сигнатура вызова, нет?

Comment: Нет, это не сигнатура вызова. Это определение типа функции

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133284/discussion-between------and-grundy).

Comment: Это всё байты, зачем ему что-то ещё проверять?

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/q/68961864/10562663

Answer (score 2):

**Внимание:** Данный ответ является переводом [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961864/how-does-the-equals-work-in-typescript/68963796#68963796)

(приведенные тут ссылки могут не работать)

Сначала давайте добавим пару скобок

```
export type Equals<X, Y> =
    (
      (<T>() => (T extends /*1st*/ X ? 1 : 2)) extends /*2nd*/
      (<T>() => (T extends /*3rd*/ Y ? 1 : 2)) 
    )
        ? true 
        : false;
```

Теперь, когда вы подставите некоторые типы вместо "X" и "Y", следующее ключевое слово "extends" как бы задает вопрос: "Является ли переменная типом `<T>() => (T extends X ? 1 : 2)` присваиваеваемым переменной типа `(<T>() => (T extends Y ? 1 : 2))`?

Другими словами мы проверяем x и y

```
declare let x: <T>() => (T extends /*1st*/ X ? 1 : 2) // Substitute an actual type for X
declare let y: <T>() => (T extends /*3rd*/ Y ? 1 : 2) // Substitute an actual type for Y
y = x // Будет ли это ошибкой или нет?
```

Автор предоставленного вами комментария говорит, что

> Правило присваиваемости для условных типов <...> требует чтобы тип после `extends` был "идентичным" это определяется проверкой типов

Здесь говорится о первом (/*1st*/) и третьем (/*3rd*/) `extends`. Средство проверки позволит присваивание `x` на `y` только в том случае, если типы после них, называемые как `X` и `Y`, идентичны.

Если вы подствите `number` для обоих:

```
declare let x: <T>() => (T extends number ? 1 : 2)
declare let y: <T>() => (T extends number ? 1 : 2)
y = x // Should this be an error or not?
```

Конечно, тут не будет ошибки, потому что есть 2 переменные одного типа.

Но если вы замените "number" на "X" и "string" на "Y":

```
declare let x: <T>() => (T extends number ? 1 : 2)
declare let y: <T>() => (T extends string ? 1 : 2)
y = x // Should this be an error or not?
```

То типы после `extends` не будут идентичны, поэтому возникнет ошибка.

---

Давайте посмотрим, почему типы после `extends` обязаны быть идентичными, чтобы переменные можно было назначать. Если они идентичны, то понятно, потому что у вас просто есть 2 переменные одного типа, они всегда будут переприсваиваться друг другу. Что касается другого случая, рассмотрим последнюю ситуацию, которую я описал, с "Equal<number, string>". Представим что если бы это не было ошибкой.

```
declare let x: <T>() => (T extends number ? 1 : 2)
declare let y: <T>() => (T extends string ? 1 : 2)
y = x // Imagine this is fine
```

Рассмотрим этот фрагмент кода:

```
declare let x: <T>() => (T extends number ? 1 : 2)
declare let y: <T>() => (T extends string ? 1 : 2)

const a = x<string>() // "a" это тип "2" потому что строка не расширяет число
const b = x<number>() // "b" это тип "1"

const c = y<string>() // "c" это тип "1" потому что строка расширяет строку
const d = y<number>() // "d" это тип "2"

y = x
// В соответствии с объявлением типа "y" мы знаем, что "e" должно быть типом "1"
// Но мы только что присвоили x y, и мы знаем, что "x" возвращает "2" в этом сценарии
// Это не валидно
const e = y<string>() 
// То же самое здесь, согласно типу "y", это должно быть "2", но так как "y" теперь "x",
// это на самом деле "1"
const f = y<number>()
```

Похоже на то, если типы не "строка" и "число", которые не имеют ничего общего, а нечто более сложное. Давайте попробуем `{foo: string, bar: number}` для `X` и `{foo: string}` для `Y`. Обратите внимание, что здесь "X" фактически присваивается "Y"

```
declare let x: <T>() => (T extends {foo: string, bar: number} ? 1 : 2)
declare let y: <T>() => (T extends {foo: string} ? 1 : 2)

// "a" имеет тип "2", потому что {foo: string} не расширяет {foo: string, bar: number}
const a = x<{foo: string}>()

// "b" is of type "1"
const b = y<{foo: string}>()

y = x
// В соответствии с объявлением типа "y" это должно быть типом "1", но мы просто
// присвоили значение x для y, и "x" возвращает "1" в этом сценарии

const c = y<{foo: string}>()
```

Если вы переключите типы и попробуете `{foo: строка}` для `X` и `{foo: строка, строка: число}` для `Y`, то снова возникнет проблема с вызовом
`y<{foo: string}>()`. Вы можете увидеть, что всегда что-то не так.

Чтобы быть более точным, если `X` и "Y" не идентичны, всегда будет какой-то тип, который расширяет один из них и не расширяет другой. И если вы попытаетесь использовать этот тип для "Т", вы получите бессмыслицу. На самом деле, если вы попытаетесь назначить `y = x`, компилятор выдаст вам такую ошибку:

```
Тип '<T>() => T extends number ? 1 : 2' is не может быть присвоен типу '<T>() => T extends string ? 1 : 2'.
  Тип 'T extends number ? 1 : 2' is не может быть присвоен типу 'T extends string ? 1 : 2'.
    Тип '1 | 2' is не может быть присвоен типу 'T extends string ? 1 : 2'.
      Тип '1' is не может быть присвоен типу 'T extends string ? 1 : 2'.
```

Поскольку всегда существует тип, который может быть присвоен одному из "X" и "Y", а не другому, он вынужден рассматривать возвращаемый тип "x" как "1/2", который не может быть присвоен "T расширяет `...` ? 1 : 2", потому что "T" может расширить это `...` - или не может.

Это в основном то, к чему сводится этот тип "Равных", надеюсь, более или менее понятно, как это работает.

---

ОБНОВЛЕНО:

Поговорим о том, почему "Equal<{x: 1} & {y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 2}>" является "ложным"

tl;dr Насколько я понимаю, это деталь реализации (не уверен, следует ли мне называть это ошибкой, может быть так задумано)

Теоретически, конечно, это должно быть "правдой". Как я описал выше, "Equal" возвращает "ложь" (теоретически) тогда и только тогда, когда существует тип "C", такой, что "C" может быть присвоен одному из "X" и "Y", но не другому. В этом случае в приведенном выше примере, если вы сделаете `x = y` и вставите его (`x<C>()` и `y<C>()`), вы получите неправильные типы. Здесь, однако, это не так, все, что может быть присвоено "{x: 1} & {y: 2}`, может быть присвоено "{x: 1, y: 2}", поэтому теоретически "Equal" должно возвращать "истину".

На практике, однако, похоже, что реализация typescript использует более ленивый подход при принятии решения о том, идентичны ли типы. Я должен отметить, что это немного предположение, я никогда не участвовал в typescript и не знаю его исходного кода, но вот что я нашел за последние 10 минут, я мог полностью пропустить некоторые детали, но идея должна быть правильной.

Файл, который выполняет проверку типа в репозитории ts, называется [checker.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0e905be42bd92d6679d43408deb818b09ff6c292/lib/tsc.js) (ссылка ведет на версию файла между ts 4.4 и 4.5, в будущем это может измениться). Здесь строка "19130" кажется местом, где буква "Т" расширяет X? 1 : 2`и`T расширяет Y? сравниваются части 1 : 2`. Вот соответствующие части:

```
// строка 19130
// Два условных типа 'T1 расширяет U1 ? X1 : Y1' и 'T2 расширяет U2 ? X2 : Y2' связаны, если
// один из T1 и T2 связан с другим, U1 и U2 являются идентичными типами, X1 связан с X2,
// и Y1 связан с Y2.
// ...
let sourceExtends = (source as ConditionalType).extendsType;
// ...
// Line 19143
if (isTypeIdenticalTo(sourceExtends, (target as ConditionalType).extendsType) && /* ... */) {
  // ...
}
```

В комментарии говорится, что эти типы связаны, если, помимо прочих условий, "U1" и "U2", в нашем случае "X" и "Y", идентичны, это именно то, что мы пытаемся проверить. В строке "19143" вы можете увидеть типы после сравнения "extends", что приводит к функции "Istypeidenticalto", которая, в свою очередь, вызывает "isTypeRelatedTo(источник, цель, идентификация)".:

```
function isTypeRelatedTo(source: Type, target: Type, relation: /* ... */) {
    // ...
    if (source === target) {
        return true;
    }
    if (relation !== identityRelation) {
        // ...
    }
    else {
        if (source.flags !== target.flags) return false;
        if (source.flags & TypeFlags.Singleton) return true;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Вы можете видеть, что сначала он проверяет, являются ли они строго одного и того же типа ( "{x: 1} & {y: 2}" и "{x: 1, y: 2}" не относятся к реализации ts), затем сравнивает их "флаги". Если вы посмотрите на определение типа "Тип" [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0e905be42bd92d6679d43408deb818b09ff6c292/lib/tsserverlibrary.d.ts#L2546) вы обнаружите, что "флаги" имеют тип "TypeFlags", который определен [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0e905be42bd92d6679d43408deb818b09ff6c292/lib/tsserverlibrary.d.ts#L2495) обратите внимание на это: у пересечения есть свой собственный флаг. Таким образом, "{x: 1} & {y: 2}" имеет флаг "Пересечение", "{x: 1, y: 2}" нет, поэтому они не связаны, поэтому "Equal" возвращает "ложь", хотя теоретически это должно быть иначе.

Comment: @Dmitry в ответе есть ссылка.

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси [Обратите внимание](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/209304) на инструменты ассоциаций, под вопрос просто перенести надо

Answer (score -1):

Предполагаю что `T` в данном случае является дополнением к используемым типам (в одном случае это `Y` в другом `X`) , в качестве доказательства собственной теории к которой я пришел путем экспериментов, привожу расширенный пример:

```
type ExtendEqual<X,Y,Z> = 
  (
    (
      <X,Y>() => 
      (Z extends X ? 1: 2) extends (Z extends Y ? 1: 2) ? 1 : 2
    ) extends
    (
      <X,Z>() =>  
      (Y extends X ? 1: 2) extends (Y extends Z ? 1: 2) ? 1 : 2
    ) &
    (
      <Z,Y>() => 
       (X extends Y ? 1: 2) extends (X extends Z ? 1: 2) ? 1 : 2
    ) ? 100 : 500
  )

const q: ExtendEqual<number, number, number> = 100 
const u: ExtendEqual<number, number, string> = 500 
const i: ExtendEqual<number, string, number> = 500 
const z: ExtendEqual<string, number, number> = 500
const o: ExtendEqual<string, string, string> = 100
const k: ExtendEqual<string, string, boolean> = 500

console.log(q, u, i, z, o, k)
```

Мое мнение заключается в том что при `<X,Y,Z>`

если мы хотим исследовать `<X>` то дополнительными будут `<Z,Y>` в принципе под любыми именами **например!** `<V,W>` и так далее. Я проверял, [работает](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7AJjAjgVwIYBsA8AGgDQCaxAWgHxQC8UAUFFABRPOvsdRFlUsBKOjS4cWFKBATIUAZyiEoAfigBGAFxQATEKmJU88ZOkGopZWs06LqqFdG6Tc0W27Ne1QcOajmLc3oy8ooqGtqO%20nKsAU7yEqFWQqF22g5QAGQuvjwAasQA6vxCtCJufoqBpvk2icaRhhWxUDk14TYpWmmhAAzdKQCsvewCDAwAxgD2SLLAUOia8JEYOARImAC2AEYQAE7EUGtbu-uH2zs09Kq9jJPTs5gLTst4%20KfHBxtn%20zM7AJZIAHMLlBBn1xlMZlBfo8llgXm89lAfv8ASdPrtgaCbhDZgAvGEyZ4EZGAtFHREIzFDW6QiYE1BE-Ak1FI4B-Ums9lAuhqak4qAAa3paDhxLZKO%204o5mwmE1wEGwSCp3VGNLlEAAdLgJgCWOh9ph9r99rj9hN9gKBEA).

В общем это как `алиасы` для дополнительных типов.

Надеюсь, кто-то подвердит мою догадку или опровергнет.

**Хочу попросить не минусовать молча, комментировать, так будет честнее, во всяком случае я не знаю как доказать обратное сделаному выводу.**

Comment: Вы уж не обижайтесь, но это ответ и не ответ. Одни сомнения. `T` это никак не алиас.

Comment: Извините, я не говорил что это `алиас` я говорил `как алиас` - это аналогия, не утверждение, можно предствить что есть какое-то количество аргументов типов формирующих генерик, так вот у них могут быть свои имена, не обязательно первоначальные XYZ это все подтверждается тем что код делает именно то что от него требуется, если хотите можете доказать обратное, я с удовольтвием соглашусь если объясните в чем я не прав кроме `терминалогии` Не воспринимайте пожалуйста это как попытку холиварить.

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси мне кстати понравился Ваш вопрос, что касается моего ответа, я хотел поделится своими исследованиями, если хотите у Вас есть возможность не отмечать его как верный, на стековерфлоу не все ответы верные.

Comment: Вопрос именно про текущую реализацию, как она работает. А вы привели свою реализацию.  *(в одном случае это Y в другом X* -  это как? Можете расписать подстановку, как с этим работает анализатор? Так же посмотрите чат, где я пытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Моя реализация вводит третий тип для того чтобы проверить мои догадки о том откуда берется `T` в вашей реализации, т.е. сугубо по вашему вопросу, разве что я не нашел пока в исходниках доказательств, в чат зайду, я так понимаю это комменты под вашим вопросом.

Comment: Так же нашел вариант, при котором ваш тип не работает `const k: ExtendEqual<{x: 1} & {y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 1} & {y: 2}> = 500`. Но можно подправить и будет работать: `type ExtendEqual1<X,Y,Z> = (<X>() => Z extends X ? 1: 2) extends (<X>() => Y extends X ? 1: 2) & (<W>() => X extends W ? 1: 2) ? 100 : 500`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133410/discussion-between------and-daniil-loban).